# Facebook and RoR: how to redirect to authorization URL?

Tags: facebook, authorization, koala

I am trying to redirect the user to the URL which requests permission to access the user's  information.

I have a view with a form whose action goes to the following:

```
class AuthController < ApplicationController

   def auth
     @oauth = Koala::Facebook::OAuth.new("*id*", "*secret*", 'http://localhost:3000/auth/auth2') 
     address = @oauth.url_for_oauth_code(:permissions => "publish_stream")
     puts "address  #{address}"
     redirect_to address
     return  
   end

   def auth2

   end

end
```

On `stdout`, address shows up as: `Redirected to https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=*id*&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/auth/auth2&scope=publish_stream`

If I enter this URL standalone in my browser (and not through my app), I get taken to the correct page where the app requests permissions. However, for through my application, I am taken to a page that shows the Facebook logo, not the page requesting permissions.

I expected to see the permissions page and then once the user allow's permission, the request forwards to my redirect_uri.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the fbml for a redirect or trying to do it server side? If your app is a canvas page and you're redirecting server side, you are only redirecting facebook, not the user. You will need to ensure you are actually telling facebook to do the redirect.

Check out [fb:redirect](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/redirect/) if that is the case.

Comment: Thanks Gats. My canvas type is iframe not fbml. I am doing the redirect server side. The documentation says fb:redirect is for legacy FBML apps.

Comment: One more thing to add, I am redirected to a page with the facebook icon and a link to Go to Facebook. Clicking that link takes me to the authorization page for my app. but I want to go directly there and not through this intermediate page.

Comment: Not sure what the solution is for iframes. I suspect you need to look at checking if a user is A: logged in and B: has authorised, then send them directly. If the user is logged into facebook I don't know what you're not seeing the auth page immediately. Sorry I can't help more.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to post the answer to my question. The solution was actually quite simple. Instead of doing the redirect to the authorization uri in my controller, I needed to do it in my view as follows. This avoided the intermediate login page and seems to be what everyone else is doing who has hit this particular problem (where an intermediate facebook page is served instead of passing the user directly to the authorization page.)

```
<script language=JavaScript>
top.location.href="https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=client_id&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/xxx&scope=publish_stream";
</script>
```

I can't say I understand why it matters and I can't redirect in the controller. So if anyone using RoR can explain why, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered a similar problem. In order to break your app out of the iframe and redirect to authorization page from a server side redirect in rails you can do i.e.:

```
def facebook_authorization
  redirect_url =<<-EOS
    <script>
      top.location.href='https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=client_id&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/xxx&scope=publish_stream';
    </script>
   EOS       

   render :inline => redirect_url
end
```

This is pretty much the the same way as described in the facebook documentation using php.

Further if the user authorizes your app, you will get the oauth_access token in the signed_request response parameter. I don't use Koala so not sure how they parse the signed request.

From testing I have found that for as long as the user has authorized your app you will get the oauth_access token back from facebook on every request. This makes it easy to detect whether the user has authorized the app or not and you avoid sending the user the auth page every time he/she visits your app.